# update sql foreach php array

Tags: php

Добрый день или вечер)

Подскажите как реализовать брать с array ключи (price,vendorcode) и обновлять их в базе данных в цикле foreach

Сам вывод array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Маска для волос с маслом Арганы Angel Glowring Hair Mask Tony Moly
            [price] => 228.0
            [vendorcode] => HR02003200
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Спрей для сияния волос Angel Glowring Hair Mist Tony Moly
            [price] => 796.0
            [vendorcode] => Т1380
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Крем-молочко для рук с экстр. банана Magic Food Banana Hand Milk Tony Moly
            [price] => 483.0
            [vendorcode] => BD03012800
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Пенка для умывания с алоэ для проблемной кожи Clean Dew Aloe Foam Cleanser Tony Moly
            [price] => 354.0
            [vendorcode] => SS02013200
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Пенка для умывания с экстрактом черники Clean Dew BlueBerry Foam Cleanser Tony Moly
            [price] => 354.0
            [vendorcode] => SS02013700
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Бальзам для очищения пор с тепл. эффектом PORE BLACK head Steam Balm Tony Moly
            [price] => 744.0
            [vendorcode] => Т1562
        )
```

Код

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('yandex.xml');

    function xml2array ( $xmlObject, $out = array () )
    {
        foreach ( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node )
            $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;

        return $out;
    }

    $yml_offers = [];
    foreach ($xml->xpath('/yml_catalog/shop') as $element) {
        foreach ($element->xpath('offers/offer') as $category) {

            $yml_offer = array();

            $yml_offer['name'] = implode(xml2array($category->name));
            $yml_offer['price'] = implode(xml2array($category->price));
            $yml_offer['vendorcode'] = implode(xml2array($category->vendorCode));

            $yml_offers[] = $yml_offer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так. На самом деле для более точного ответа не хватает структуры таблицы и подробного описания, что и каким образом вы хотите обновлять.

Для выполнения однотипных операций вставки или изменения используйте [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php). Они:

1. Безопасны. Так как перед подстановкой параметров в запрос они автоматом проверяются и экранируются.
2. Работают быстрее (когда их выполняется более одного)
3. Делают код на порядок удобочитаемее

.

```
$db = mew mysqli(.....);

$yml_offers = [];
$yml_offer = ['name'=>'','price'=>0,'vendorcode'=>''];

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET price=? vendorcode=? WHERE name=?');
$stmt->bind_params('iss', $yml_offer['price'], $yml_offer['vendorcode'], $yml_offer['name']);

foreach ($xml->xpath('/yml_catalog/shop') as $element) {
    foreach ($element->xpath('offers/offer') as $category) {
        $yml_offer['name'] = implode(xml2array($category->name));
        $yml_offer['price'] = implode(xml2array($category->price));
        $yml_offer['vendorcode'] = implode(xml2array($category->vendorCode));

        $stmt->execute();

        $yml_offers[] = $yml_offer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$mysqli->query("UPDATE table SET price=".$yml_offer['price']." name='".$yml_offer['name']."' vendorcode ='".$yml_offer['vendorcode']."' WHERE id=".key($category))
```

Comment: и вставить в этот цикл ?  foreach ($element->xpath('offers/offer') as $category) {

Comment: @AndryLomakin,по идее да

Comment: Это очень приочень плохое решение. Прям вот никогда не надо так делать.

Comment: @rjhdby, аргументируйте почему , мне тоже интересно

Comment: @rjhdby Все работает  )
Пожалуйста скажите почему и если можно покажите как стоит делать

Comment: Потому, что вы не знаете, что может оказаться в  `$yml_offer['vendorcode']`. Например такое `"";DROP DATABASE database;`.

Comment: @rjhdby, причем тут это суть вопроса не в защите от sql-иньекций) Минусовать ответ только за то что я не расписала защиту... Хотя ответ и дала на ПОСТАВЛЕННЫЙ вопрос...

Comment: @Nataly вы показали человеку как использовать крайне некрасивое и потенциально небезопасное решение. Попросту научили его расставлять в коде костыли.

Comment: @rjhdby, а я что-то не пойму здесь нужно прям программу написать со всеми нюансами и проверками?) Вопрос был обновление данных в базе в цикле, я ответила на него...

Comment: @Nataly здесь нужно стараться как минимум не говнокодить, извините мой французский